# How to find a percent less than a number?

Tags: percentages

I need to calculate 9.7 percent less than 17100000, but I think it would be way better if someone could please explain this to me. Thank you

Comment: Or just multiply by $1-.097=.903$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If 17,100,000 is 100%, then $100x=17,100,100$, can you then solve for $x$ and find $100x-9.7x=90.3x$?